# How do I delete a message with a Telegram bot?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm coding my own Telegram bot using python and I want to delete messages inside of a groupchat that will occur. I want to delete any message with the words "Escrow Wallet" and then instead I want to add my own message that will send the correct message after 3 minutes.

My code is:

```
import os
import time
import telebot

my_secret = os.environ['API_KEY']
API_KEY = os.getenv('API_KEY')

bot = telebot.TeleBot(my_secret)



@bot.message_handler(commands=["auth"])
def auth(message):
  
  time.sleep(3 * 60)
  
  bot.send_message(message.chat.id, " @log2, the funds have been deposited in the escrow wallet. You can go ahead and deliver the product(s) to the buyer. When @Audio is satisfied, he can paste /release into the chat or /contact in case of a dispute\n\n  The seller can also /refund the buyer!")

  @bot.message_handler(commands=["balance"])
  def auth(message):
    #add code here to delete messages from other users who may type in /balance so that my other bot cannot input the incorrect message
    time.sleep(2 * 60)
    
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, " ESCROW WALLET\n\n Wait for the balance to show up here, then continue with the deal. The funds will show up after 1 blockchain confirmation.\n\n BALANCE: 0.00775835 BTC [$1730.94]")
```

I want to add the code to the balance command so that when users type in /balance on telegram it will delete the message that the other bot says for this command. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
import os
import time
import telebot
import re

my_secret = os.environ['API_KEY']
API_KEY = os.getenv('API_KEY')


bot = telebot.TeleBot(my_secret)

@bot.message_handler(commands=["auth"])
def auth(message):
    time.sleep(3 * 60)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, " @log2, the funds have been deposited in the escrow wallet. You can go ahead and deliver the product(s) to the buyer. When @Audio is satisfied, he can paste /release into the chat or /contact in case of a dispute\n\n  The seller can also /refund the buyer!")

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: re.search(r'escrow wallet', message.text, re.IGNORECASE))
def delete_escrow_wallet_message(message):
    bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)

@bot.message_handler(commands=["balance"])
def balance(message):
    time.sleep(2 * 60)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, " ESCROW WALLET\n\n Wait for the balance to show up here, then continue with the deal. The funds will show up after 1 blockchain confirmation.\n\n BALANCE: 0.00775835 BTC [$1730.94]")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

In this code, the re.search function is used with the re.IGNORECASE flag to perform a case-insensitive search for the phrase "escrow wallet" within the message text. This means it will match "ESCROW WALLET," "escrow wallet," and any other variations of letter case. If a match is found, the message will be deleted.